# why std::push_back() behaves like std::emplace_back()

Tags: c++, move-semantics

Consider this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
 
struct CN {
    std::string s;
     CN()  { std::cout << " default constructed\n"; }
    CN(std::string str) : s(std::move(str))  { std::cout << " constructed\n"; }
    CN(const CN& o) : s(o.s) { std::cout << " copy constructed\n"; }
    CN(CN&& o) : s(std::move(o.s)) { std::cout << " move constructed\n"; }
    CN& operator=(const CN& other) {
        s = other.s;
        std::cout << " copy assigned\n";
        return *this;
    }
    CN& operator=(CN&& other) {
        s = std::move(other.s);
        std::cout << " move assigned\n";
        return *this;
    }
};
 
int main()
{
    std::vector<CN> container;
    // reserve enough place so vector does not have to resize
    //container.reserve(5);
    std::cout << "construct 2 times CN:\n";
    CN two { "two" };
    CN three { "three" };
 
    //std::cout << "emplace:\n";
    //container.emplace(container.end(), "one");
    //container.push_back(container.end(), "one");
 
    std::cout << "emplace with CN&:\n";
    //container.emplace(container.end(), two);
    container.push_back(two);
 
    std::cout << "emplace with CN&&:\n";
    //container.emplace(container.end(), std::move(three));
    container.push_back( std::move(three));
 
    std::cout << "content:\n";
    for (const auto& obj : container)
        std::cout << ' ' << obj.s;
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

the output is:

```
construct 2 times CN:
 constructed
 constructed
emplace with CN&:
 copy constructed
emplace with CN&&:
 move constructed
 copy constructed
content:
 two three
```

but I don't understand why it calls the move constructor and then the copy constructor at the last push_back? Also, why does push_back behaves here like the emplace_back, I mean, I thought that push_back first constructs the object in the vector and then makes a copy, as opposed to emplace_back which creates, or copies, or moves the object directly into the vector without the need for the object being previously created in the vector?

It seems strange. I do not understand.

Comment: `push_back` can move too: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back `emplace_back` can construct in place without even a move

Comment: If you make the move ctor and move assignment operator `noexcept` it will use those instead.

Comment: The copy constructor in the last `push_back` is likely due to reallocation - the vector needs to grow from one element to two elements, so it needs to copy the first element to the new storage. If you do `container.reserve(2)` up front, this copy should disappear.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Good point, that one always catches people out.

Comment: Your move constructor `CN(CN&& o)` is **not** `noexcept`.  This prevents some move operations within `std::vector` and falls back to copying.

Comment: The way you use `emplace_back` is equivalent to `push_back`. The interesting use of `emplace_back` would be something like `container.emplace_back("four");` This should print "constructed" and avoid either copy or move (barring reallocation) - the element would be constructed directly within the vector's storage using `CN(std::string str)` constructor.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik You are right, reserve(2) fixes it. Now I understand. Thanks! But I still don't understand why push_back behaves like emplace_back()? Is it an optimization from the compiler? I mean, in the code above, push_back does not construct, it only copy constructs.

Comment: @LiviuDorobantu You wrote "I thought that push_back first constructs the object in the vector and then makes a copy" but that's wrong. The copy ctor is a ctor, and already turns "raw memory" (so to speak) into an object. It doesn't require an object to be already there. The main difference between `emplace` and `push` is that `push` takes as argument an object (which must already exist) while `emplace` takes instead the arguments of a `CN` constructor (e.g. a string). The latter does not require an object to exist in advance. However, you pass an object in both cases, so no difference.

Comment: @chi Ohh, now I get it. std::emplace_back() is the same as std::push_back() when an object is passed as argument, but when the arguments of the constructor are passed in std::emplace_back() or std::emplace for that matter, then they are totally different things. Ok. Thanks! I almost lost my mind trying to understand this difference.